# Joomla: Parameters of List Section Layout are not inherited

Tags: inheritance, properties, menu, joomla

I am Joomla I have a menu item that lists categories in a section. I have changed some of the parameters (like 'do not display headers'). It works on the initial category listing, however after navigating into categories from that page, these parameters no longer apply.

For example, lets say we have a menu item 'News' with some properties applied. After navigating to News > Latest, these properties no longer apply.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say why your problem arises without detailed information about your settings, but I am going to venture a guess that you have sub-menu items or menu items in another menu for your categories such as Latest.

I am venturing this guess because that would explain your problem. If you have menu items for categories, then the settings for those will override those of your section overview menu item.

In Joomla there are three levels of settings that will have an impact on your section and category overview pages (be they list or blog views). THe most general settings are those in the article manager parameters. These are overridden by the settings of the relevant menu item. If there are parent and child menu items, then the settings in the lowest level menu item will prevail. Finally all the foregoing settings can be set aside by the article settings in the article edit view.

So, my best guess is that you have to check if you have submenu items and what settings you have there.